# Showing data from database 15 mnute earlier and stop showing it 15 minute late from the time set for it

Tags: mysql, sql

```
$query = "SELECT title,time_strt,ampmstrt,time_end,ampmend
          FROM addfunction
          WHERE (NOW() + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) BETWEEN time_strt AND time_end AND location = 'MAWAR ROOM'";
```

Comment: and the question is ???? ... you have errors ?    .

Comment: do you need rows that start and/or end time be in this range: (NOW-15MIN NOW+15MIN) ?

Comment: i'm sorry forgot to mention the code now is showing the data 15 minute earlier than the time_strt and stop showing the data 15 minute earlier than the time_end too.. what i want is to stop showing the data only after 15 minute have elapsed from the time_end not 15 minute earlier than the time_end. and the data type for the time_strt and time_end is DATETIME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

topo,

i hope i understand it correctly...

```
select title,time_strt,ampmstrt,time_end,ampmend 
FROM addfunction 
where UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_strt) >= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - 15 * 60) 
and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_end) >= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) + 15 * 60) 
AND location = 'MAWAR ROOM';
```

This will found all rows start 15 minutes before time_strt and ends 15 minutes after time_end.

Comment: Greater than, greater than... are you sure?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Harley.! But this query are showing my data all the time no matter what the time is. Forgot to mention im using datetime data type for the time_strt and time_end.

Comment: Hi C.topo, i have update the answere. UNIX_TIMESTAMP parse datetime into unixtime. I think it is always better to work with unixtime because it is an simple integer.

Comment: Thanks again for your help @harley81 ! Just some more question can i set a date for the NOW() function? So that it only get the data when the date is matched with the date in the time_strt column and not showing it everyday.

Comment: With date_format( time_start,'%d.%m.%Y' ) you get the Format '30.12.2017'. So you can write: and date_format(time_start,'%d.%m.%Y' ) = '30.12.2017' and you fetch all rows at this day

Comment: now() can replace with string '2017-03-14 18:00:00'

Answer (score 0):

Ended doing it like this which show the data from database 15 minute earlier than time_strt and stop Showing after 15 minute have elapsed from the time_end. I changed the data type from DATETIME to TIME.  Thanks to evryone and mostly @harley81!

```html
WHERE date = CURDATE() AND time_strt <= (CURTIME() + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AND time_end >= (CURTIME() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AND location = 'MAWAR ROOM'";
```